# Option for nvarchar field type in MySQL database

Tags: mysql, nvarchar

I want to insert data like e.g. `Visha'l` in my MySQL 5.x database, but the field type `nvarchar`required to accept this special character is not available in MySQL data field type.

Any other field type by which I can input `'` this special character in my db?

Comment: *Exact duplicate:* [mysql equivalent data types](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2214901)

Comment: names Like - Na'makaran'a, Visha'l, Visha'la', Pran'av, Ta'pas etc  has to be added to database.