# Storing 30k-char strings, should I use NVARCHAR(max)?

Tags: sql, store

From what I fond on internet, I should be using NVARCHAR(max) to store some strings that contain up to 30k characters. I don't need to search through the strings, only store and retrieve it. The type TEXT seems obsolete, and VARCHAR isn't as friendly as NVARCHAR about Unicode, so I should be using NVARCHAR(max), right ?

Secondly, for now I'm using some sql database of a free webhosting service, i'm creating the structure via the phpmyadmin, and when creating columns it doesn't suggest NVARCHAR, only VARCHAR and other types. Is NVARCHAR still available, maybe with a DDL command ? The sql version is 5.5.32

Thanks and sorry if my questions are unclear, i'm kind of a newb

Comment: Nvarchar(max) is SQL Server. You seem to be using MySQL.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214901/mysql-equivalent-data-types