# Create an NVARCHAR column in MySQL using code first?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

So, unlike SQL Server, in MySQL, the following property creates a column of type `LONGTEXT`:

```
public string Name { get; set; }
```

I want to have an `NVARCHAR(255)` column instead, so I tried the following:

```
//[DataType("NVARCHAR"), StringLength(255)]     // creates a varchar(255) column.
[DataType("NVARCHAR"), MaxLength(255)]          // creates a varchar(255) column.
public string Name { get; set; }
```

I also tried the following with Fluent API:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
    .Property(p => p.Name)
    .HasColumnType("NVARCHAR")
    .HasMaxLength(255);             // still creates a varchar(255) column.
```

..and:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>()
    .Property(p => p.Name)
    .HasColumnType("NVARCHAR(255)");
```

Which causes an `InvalidOperationException` with the following message:

> The store type 'NVARCHAR(255)' could not be found in the MySql
>   provider manifest

**Is there something I'm doing wrong? What is the correct way to create an nvarchar column using code-first?**

Comment: mysql does not have `nvarchar` type.

Comment: You're right, turns out it was just an alias in MySQL Workbench which maps to varchar with `utf8` collation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySql does not have `NVARCHAR` type. For alternative solutions consult:
[mysql equivalent data types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214901/mysql-equivalent-data-types)

Comment: Thanks, I've been misled somehow by the `NVARCHAR` alias in MySQL Workbench.