# What is the difference between varchar and nvarchar with the same character set and collation in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anyone tell me what is the difference between varchar and nvarchar with the same character set and collate. Example:

```
varchar CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

and

```
nvarchar CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Thank you!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Actually, MySQL do not have nvarchar() data types [Click here for details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214901/mysql-equivalent-data-types?lq=1)

varchar() and nvarchar() are data types of sql-server and the difference is nvarchar support and unicode character mainly use for internationalisation but varchar() do not support unicode. [details for sql-server nvarchar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144283/what-is-the-difference-between-varchar-and-nvarchar)

Comment: Can i ask you for one more? Does the ascii character set require less bytes per character than ther utf8mb4 character set. Is there any difference between them if there is 2 table with same data but using 2 diff character set

Comment: Exactly, Ascii character set requires less bytes(space) then utf8mb4 but it does not support for all international language and emoji. So, utf8mb4  is used more. I think two tables are created to consume less space, But nowadays space is not importance over the importance of unicode support

Comment: Thank you again. But if a have column which store non utf8 data such as password or some kind of string id, should i use the ascii character set for it or just apply utf8mb4 for all column in database because you said space was not importance over the importance of unicode support.

Comment: Actually, utf8mb4 is compatible with all OS and Databases which  comes to be great importance when you need to migrate database or OS in future. Hence I suggest to use utf8mb4

Comment: OK thank you for helping me. Have a nice day!

Comment: The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/charset-national.html) seems to differ from your answer.