# I'm learning SQL by myself , when I create a query but I have an error (invalid name of 'Employee') when I insert it

Tags: sql

Step 1: create a new database

```
CREATE DATABASE MyfirstDatabase;
```

Step 2:

```
USE MyFirstDatabase
```

Step 3 create an `employee` table inside `MyFirstDatabase`:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee
(
    EmpID nvarchar(50), 
    Name nvarchar(50),
    DOB Date
);
```

Step 4: insert values into `Employee` table:

```
INSERT INTO Employee 
VALUES ('E01', 'John', '3 November 2000');

INSERT INTO Employee 
VALUES ('E02', 'Kelly', '24 November 2000');

DROP DATABASE MyfirstDatabase
```

Comment: Another problem is that your DOB values are in the wrong format. '3 November  2000' should be '2000-11-03'.

Comment: Before inserting, try executing SELECT query i.e. SELECT * FROM Employee to see whether the table exists or not. I suspect its happening due to the incorrect scheme owner or permission.

Comment: While I agree the date string format should be yyyy-mm-dd, that exact code works as is here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/62febe/1

Comment: @SOS It works with MS SQL Server, not MySQL. The question was only tagged "SQL", not with a specific RDBMS, so it's not clear which is correct.

Comment: @kmoser - True it's not tagged. Though I don't think MySQL has data type `nvarchar`.

Comment: @SOS [MySQL supports `nvarchar`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13922851/378779)

Comment: @kmoser - Duh! Thanks for that. Don't know how I missed it (TIL)

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

After creating databse `MyFirstDatabase` and table `Employee`

```sql
USE MyFirstDatabase;

INSERT INTO Employee VALUES
('E01','John','2000-11-03');

INSERT INTO Employee VALUES
('E02','Kelly','2000-11-24');
```

Date format should be in `yyyy-MM-dd` format